# Autocomplete textview with oval shape corners

Tags: android, xml, background, shapes, android-drawable

I want to create the shape of autocomplete textview shown in the figure and text should come in center of it.

[image]

Currently I am trying to implement it as

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="15dip" />

        <solid android:color="@color/blue_text" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dip"
            android:left="15dip"
            android:right="15dip"
            android:top="5dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/autoComp"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="@drawable/bg_autocompletetext"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

But it would just make the corners of the textview round. It does make it completely round. Please specify any solution for it.

Comment: you can set the height of your autoTextview to 48dp(default height) and then provide corner radius of 24dp to your shape. thats how I did it in my project. Remove wrapcontent for height

Comment: Use a 9-patch background.

Comment: @IllegalArgument it does'nt work that way

Answer (score 2):

try this code of shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
  android:shape="rectangle" >

   <corners
    android:radius="100dp"/>
   <solid
    android:color="#2137FF"/>
   <size
    android:width="250dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

try this [**tool**](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

Comment: Same means? as you ask that type of shape generate and what you want ?? see updated answer (tool)

Comment: means i am getting old result, only corners gets rounded. but i want left and right sides completely round

Comment: share image what you want

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use 9 patch image as a background of your TextView.

With using 9 patch image you can set proper resolution for different resolution device.And it will give you better result .

Answer (score 0):

You write a seperate xml layout(shape.xml) having code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="#DCDCDC" />    
<stroke android:width="2.5dp" 
android:color="#DCDCDC" />
<corners
android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in your main layout add:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autoComp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/shape"
android:textColor="@color/white"
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, working for rounded text view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_textview.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#284A89" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Following file in drawables "searchtextbox_border.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/light_grey"
        android:width="1dp">
    </stroke>
</shape>
```

Then Add it as background in your AutocompleteTextview as follows:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchtextbox_border"
        android:hint="Search" />
```